# static_pointer_cast through inheritance and template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

I am having trouble finding a fix for the following error, thrown when compiling a `std::static_pointer_cast<>()`:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ecse::EventSubscriptionManager<ecse::BaseEvent>* to type ecse::EventSubscriptionManager<TestEvent>*
```

I have the following hierarchy. In the end they will be filled with POD type members and will most likely become structs.

```
class BaseEvent {};

template <class E>
class Event : public BaseEvent, public Type<E> {};

class TestEvent : public Event<TestEvent> {};
```

I am currently working on the Subscribe function part of the EventManager, however when compiling I am receiving the error posted above. Note: `E::ID()` is defined in the class as Type and is used for identifying the class type.

```
template <class E>
class EventSubscriptionManager
{
public:
  void Subscribe(std::function<void(E)>  fptr);
private:
  std::function<void(E)> event_function_;
};

class EventManager
{
public:
  template <class E>
  void Subscribe(std::function<void(E)> fptr)
  {
     std::shared_ptr<EventSubscriptionManager<E>> sub_manager_ptr;
     auto sub_manager_iterator = sub_managers_.find(E::ID());
     if(sub_manager_iterator == sub_managers_.end())
     {
       sub_manager_ptr = std::make_shared<EventSubscriptionManager<E>>();
     }
     else
     {
       sub_manager_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<EventSubscriptionManager<E>>(sub_manager_iterator->second);
     }
     // Continue function...
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<EventSubscriptionManager<BaseEvent>>> sub_managers_;
}
```

I believe that the issue is that between the `TestEvent` and the `BaseEvent` there is the `Event<E>` class with the template, with `TestEvent` inheriting `Event<TestEvent>` instead of `BaseEvent`. Is this true? If so, how can I set up my hierarchy to allow for this type of casting?

If that is not the case, what is the issue with the above static cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you why it does not compile. This is because

```
EventSubscriptionManager<E>
```

is unrelated to

```
EventSubscriptionManager<BaseEvent>
```

So, according to  [point 1.)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) on the reference page,

```
static_cast<EventSubscriptionManager<E>*>((EventSubscriptionManager<BaseEvent>*)nullptr)
```

is ill-formed.

However, without knowing the background I can't tell what to do as a workaround.
Just: you have to relate the two classes, or choose a completely new design.

---

---

In order to do so, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/002c87debc2fa835) is a minimal example why it fails which might be helpful:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

template<typename T>
struct Foo {};

int main()
{
   static_cast<Foo<Derived>*>((Foo<Base>*)nullptr);
}
```

You can try to improve on that.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. Between yours and erenon's answer, I gathered that instead of using BaseEvent inside the Subscription Manager template I should create a BaseEventSubscriptionManager to go inside the std::unordered_map template.

Comment: I took the link you provided and edited it to show my new direction, simply so I can save it for later. [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/729d9edd5a4d331a)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, there is no covariance or contravariance, there is no relationship between `T<Base>` and `T<Sub>`, even if there is one between `Base` and `Sub`.

You either need to build a common ancestor of different `EventSubscriptionManager` instances (e.g: `EventSubscriptionManagerBase`), and use that, or provide a converting constructor.